# Asynchronous / Deferred JavaScript issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, async-await, jquery-deferred

I am using this code at footer for Eliminate render-blocking resources

```
<script async or defer src="/jquery.js">
 /* custom code  */
<script>    
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.menu-bar').click(function(){
   $('.nav-bar').slideToggle();
  }); 
  $('.dropdown').click(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass('inDrop');
      $('.dropdown-menu').slideToggle('slow');
  });

});
</script>
```

Now I am getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` error.

what is best way to use Asynchronous / Deferred JavaScript

Comment: You can't have code inside a script with `src`. They need to be separate `<script>` tags.

Comment: And you can't use `async` if you need to use the library in another script tag.

Comment: @Barmar , Yes i was forgot to add here. i updated code now.

Comment: You need to break your script tag on top as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Async is tough, because it'll execute the minute it finishes, so you can't tell the order in which scripts will finish being retrieved. It's also negligible compared to defer, which will wait until the HTML parses before it starts, and then it starts in order.

Here are two cases:

```
<HTML start>
<async js 1>
<async js 2 (dep on 1)>
<HTML parses>
<js 2 finishes and executes>
<js 1 finishes and executes>
<HTML finishes parsing>
```

Defer:

```
<HTML start>
<defer js 1>
<defer js 2 (dep on 1)>
<js 2 loads, and waits>
<js 1 loads, and waits>
<HTML finishes parsing>
<js 1 is fired>
<js 2 is fired>
```

You can keep your dependencies with `defer`. I use defer 99.9% of the time, and only if the order of your scripts is not important.

If you need the inline js to *wait* until the dependencies are loaded, you would wait for the document ready state.

jQuery:

```
`$(document).ready(function() {
  ...code here...
};`
```

vanilla JS:

```
`document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  ...code here...
};`
```

Comment: <script  defer src="/jquery.js">
 /* custom code  */
<script defer >    
$(document).ready(function(){

});
</script>

is this code correct ?

Comment: ***Edit*** I misread. Yes. Calling jQuery first and both deferred will make it stay dependent.

Comment: its working if i use JS file for custom code. but not working for inline js code

Comment: Well yes. Because *inline* js is *in* the HTML that's being parsed. You can't defer a library the inline HTML depends on because it would *defer* behind the inline code.

Comment: What you would do is wrap your code in a loaded/ready state. Like this: `$(document).ready(function() { ...code here...}` without jQuery: `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { ...code here... };`